# RemoteEvent not firing

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a game where you can spawn at certain points when you click play, I am trying to fire a RemoteEvent in the LocalScript below:

```
frame.PlazaSpawn.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    switchteams.Transparency = 0
    switchteams.TextTransparency = 0
    switchteams.Active = true
    game.ReplicatedStorage.PlazaActive:FireServer()
```

I then make a function in a Script in ServerScriptService which tries to detect when the event is fired

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.PlazaActive.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
            print("Handeled!")      
            game.StarterGui.TeamSelection.TeamSelectandBalance.Location.Value = "Plaza"
```

When I click on the button named "PlazaSpawn" the message in the above code isn't printed and the value "Location" shows up as nothing

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT: I somehow made it so that the Script detected the RemoteEvent fire, investigating further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested this. It works. I'm not sure what your issue is. If you're trying to change a GUI with this code, you're referencing StarterGUI instead of the Player's GUI. If you're not, then I don't know what the question fully is. You should check for errors in the Output and spelling/caps errors.